# Testing Next.js API with Jest and Supertest library: incorrect request object in POST route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, supertest, next-api

I encountered an issue during tests launch for Next.js API call. It's just JWT authentication request with Next and Jose library. I can't recognize a response object to check its body, status and headers at least. Thus, the problem is to get correct `request` argument into Jest environment to test the request as it's working well into browser and Postman

I got **route.js** API route file:

```
import { SignJWT } from "jose";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getJwtSecretKey } from "@/libs/auth";

export async function POST(request) {
    try {
        const body = await request.json();
        if (body.username === "test-name" && body.password === "password1234") {
            const token = await new SignJWT({
                username: body.username,
            })
                .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
                .setIssuedAt()
                .setExpirationTime("30s")
                .sign(getJwtSecretKey());
            const response = NextResponse.json(
                { success: true },
                { status: 200, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
            );
            response.cookies.set({
                name: "token",
                value: token,
                path: "/",
            });
            // Temporary stub for user profile
            response.cookies.set({
                name: "user-name",
                value: body.username,
                path: "/api",
            });
            return response;
        }
        return NextResponse.json(
            { success: false },
            { status: 401, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        return console.error(error)
    }
}
```

I'm using `console.error` here to expose exact exception to console

The test file is:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { POST } from './route';
import { getJwtSecretKey } from '../../../libs/auth';
import * as Jose from "jose";

jest.mock('../../../libs/auth', () => ({
    getJwtSecretKey: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('next/dist/server/web/exports/next-response.js', () => ({ Request: jest.fn() }));

jest.mock('jose', () => ({
    SignJWT: jest.fn(() => Jose.SignJWT)
}));

describe('POST API Endpoint', () => {
    it('should return a success response with a token for valid credentials', async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers('legacy');
        getJwtSecretKey.mockReturnValue('your-secret-key');

        const validCredentials = {
            username: 'test-name',
            password: 'password1234',
        };
 
        const response = await request(POST)
            .post('/api/login')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .send(JSON.stringify(validCredentials));
        ;
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body).toEqual({ success: true });
        expect(response.headers['content-type']).toBe('application/json');
        expect(response.header['set-cookie']).toContain('token=');
    });
    // Other test cases here
});
```

The test result is:

```
  console.error
    TypeError: request.json is not a function
        at Server.json (C:\Users\smiss-dev\projects\auth-jwt\src\app\api\login\route.js:7:36)
        at Server.emit (node:events:517:28)
        at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:1107:12)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)

      33 |         return NextResponse.json({ success: false });
      34 |     } catch (error) {
    > 35 |         console.error(error)
         |                 ^
      36 |     }
      37 | }

      at Server.error (src/app/api/login/route.js:35:17)

 FAIL  src/app/api/login/route.test.js (5.487 s)
  POST API Endpoint
    × should return a success response with a token for valid credentials (5002 ms)

  ● POST API Endpoint › should return a success response with a token for valid credentials

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."

      15 |
      16 | describe('POST API Endpoint', () => {
    > 17 |     it('should return a success response with a token for valid credentials', async () => {
         |     ^
      18 |         jest.useFakeTimers('legacy');
      19 |         getJwtSecretKey.mockReturnValue('your-secret-key');
      20 |

      at it (src/app/api/login/route.test.js:17:5)
      at Object.describe (src/app/api/login/route.test.js:16:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.911 s, estimated 6 s
Ran all test suites matching /route/i.
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
```

It looks that request is falling into `catch` block and request object does not consist `json`, hence the request has timeout and the test is not completed

The first of all I've checked the `request` object and I found out that the body also absent here:
`const body = await request.body` exposes `undefined`.
Also the request is not `NextRequest` object.

I've applied "http" library to test the request:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { POST } from './route';
import { getJwtSecretKey } from '../../../libs/auth';
import { createServer } from "http";
import * as Jose from "jose";

jest.mock('../../../libs/auth', () => ({
    getJwtSecretKey: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('next/dist/server/web/exports/next-response.js', () => ({ Request: jest.fn() }));

jest.mock('jose', () => ({
    SignJWT: jest.fn(() => Jose.SignJWT)
}));

describe('POST API Endpoint', () => {
    let server;

    beforeAll(() => {
        server = createServer(POST);
        server.listen();
    });

    afterAll((done) => {
        server.close(done);
    });
    it('should return a success response with a token for valid credentials', async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers('legacy');
        getJwtSecretKey.mockReturnValue('your-secret-key');

        const validCredentials = {
            username: 'test-name',
            password: 'password1234',
        };

        const response = await request(server)
            .post('/api/login')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .send(JSON.stringify(validCredentials));
        ;
        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body).toEqual({ success: true });
        expect(response.headers['content-type']).toBe('application/json');
        expect(response.header['set-cookie']).toContain('token=');
    });
    // Other tests here
});
```

Result is the same

**jest.config.js:**

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest')

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
    dir: './',
})

const customJestConfig = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
}

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig)
```

Comment: Your handler returns undefined if you catch an error, so the endpoint never responds, so the test times out. It's telling you the right thing.

Comment: It's exactly that I'm trying to solve. Supertest returns `undefined` at `request.json` thus it throws the exception. How can I fix the test?

Comment: The first problem is not in your test at all, it's in the implementation's (lack of) handling of errors.

Comment: It's just a first positive test case, its purpose to check whether main request's flow works good, it's fair enough to get it work for starters